# Set border on the div with biggest height

Tags: css

I have two divs set side by side, and I need to set a border between them.

The problem is that they have different heights which modifies depending on some results. Sometimes the height of the left div is bigger than that of the right one and sometimes it's reverse. The border should be set border-right if the left div is bigger or border-left if the right one is bigger.

I can't control the height of the divs, it is set dynamically.
Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Please post your markup and CSS, or make a fiddle.

Comment: Usually an easy solution for this: Set border on both elements, and make them “overlap” by a negative margin of the border width …

Comment: I tried this and where they overlap the border is thicker..

Comment: Here's a fiddle using @CBroe's suggestion:  http://jsfiddle.net/z20hjjr7/  Note the negative left margin on the second div.

Comment: And here's a fiddle that sets the border based on the tallest div:  http://jsfiddle.net/7wqk9fp0/.  But @CBroe's CSS solution seems cleaner.

Comment: yes, that works, thanks. would you add your answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Comment: Sure, but if @CBroe decides to post his solution, he should get credit.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: I’ll pass, you take it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CBroe deserves credit for this solution:

> Set border on both elements, and make them “overlap” by a negative
>   margin of the border width.

[**Working Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/z20hjjr7/)

If your CSS is a bit more complicated (a margin between the divs?), you can set the border to the tallest div by comparing their `offsetHeight`s:

```
var d1= document.querySelector('#D1'),
    d2= document.querySelector('#D2');

if(d1.offsetHeight > d2.offsetHeight) {
  d1.style.borderRight= '1px solid green';
}
else {
  d2.style.borderLeft= '1px solid green';
}
```

[**Working Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wqk9fp0/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a border via a container element like this:

The following solution simply puts a border on the pseudo element `:before` that is centered inside the `.container` containing the two children elements.

### http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/5gtwdx4d/

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left" style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="right" style="height: 200px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left" style="height: 200px;"></div>
    <div class="right" style="height: 100px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left" style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="right" style="height: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container { /*important for the border */
    position: relative;
    width: 400px; /* 2x children*/
}
.container:after {  /* clearfix */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.container:before { /* border */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: dashed 2px  #cc3300;
}

.container { 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left, .right { 
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.left {
    background-color: #33cc00;
}
.right {
    background-color: #0033cc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want to do is create a jQuery function to check the hight of the taller of the two elements and apply the border styling on it. Since you haven't provided any mockup of the html/css I can only guess what the class names are:

```
    var leftDiv = $('.classOfLeftDiv').height();
    var rightDiv = $('.classOfRightDiv').height();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (leftDiv > rightDiv){
            $('.classOfLeftDiv').css('border-right' : '1px solid #abcdef');
        }else{
            $('.classOfRightDiv').css('border-left' : '1px solid #abcdef');
        }
    });
```